# How to get all valid urls from website?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I'm doing a web scraping project of [this website](https://lsdb.eu/).

At this moment what I'd like to do is to scrape artist name from an url like this: `https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/225/`

As there is an artist set to number 225, the page exists. However, `https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/226/` does not exist, but there are pages with higher numbers than 226 that do exist.

Is there any way to scrape the website to see which `https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/xxx/` urls are valid?

Comment: You could wrap the scrape inside of `try` so that it simply skips over bad urls and goes to the next one. Alternatively `httr::GET` allows for access to the sites response so `GET("https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/225/")$status_code` will return 200 (good), whereas  `GET("https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/226/")$status_code` will return 404 (bad)

Answer (score 0):

The site responds to HTTP `HEAD` requests which are generally friendlier to sites as they usually take fewer resources (at a minimum, no content is returned, so it saves time and bandwidth). You can do something like the following:

```
library(httr)

is_valid_artist <- function(x) {
  httr::status_code(httr::HEAD(sprintf("https://lsdb.eu/artists/view/%s/", x)))
}

is_valid_artist("225")
## [1] 200

is_valid_artist("226")
## [1] 404 

is_valid_artist("42437")
## [1] 200

is_valid_artist("100000000")
## [1] 404
```

If you choose to make a series of sequential lookups add some pause between requests as you could still DoS the site. For full content pulls 5-10s is suggested but for `HEAD` requests you could ethically make it 1 second (IMO).